# Custom attribut value don't save in editing product from back-end

Tags: magento2, product, save, product-edit, modifier

I've had a custom select option in the product edit in the backend.
When I try to save the product, my option is not saved.

Here the code :

**di.xml**

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <virtualType name="Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\Pool">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="modifiers" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="ntdd_product_conf" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="class" xsi:type="string">           Vendor\Module\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\NewField
                    </item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">70</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
</config>
```

**NewField.php**

```
    <?php

    namespace 
    Vendor\Module\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier;

    use Magento\Catalog\Model\Locator\LocatorInterface;
    use 
  Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\AbstractModifier;
    use Magento\Framework\Stdlib\ArrayManager;
    use Magento\Framework\UrlInterface;
    use Magento\Ui\Component\Container;
    use Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Fieldset;
    use Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Element\DataType\Text;
    use Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Element\Select;
    use Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Field;

class DateDelivery extends AbstractModifier
{

    // Components indexes
    const CUSTOM_FIELDSET_INDEX   = 'ntdd_product_conf';
    const CUSTOM_FIELDSET_CONTENT = 'ntdd_product_conf_content';
    const CONTAINER_HEADER_NAME   = 'ntdd_product_conf_content_header';

    // Fields names
    const FIELD_NAME_SELECT = 'ntdd_ready_days';

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Locator\LocatorInterface
     */
    protected $locator;

    /**
     * @var ArrayManager
     */
    protected $arrayManager;

    /**
     * @var UrlInterface
     */
    protected $urlBuilder;

    /**
     * @var array
     */
    protected $meta = [];

    /**
     * @param LocatorInterface $locator
     * @param ArrayManager $arrayManager
     * @param UrlInterface $urlBuilder
     */
    public function __construct(
        LocatorInterface $locator,
        ArrayManager $arrayManager,
        UrlInterface $urlBuilder
    ) {
        $this->locator = $locator;
        $this->arrayManager = $arrayManager;
        $this->urlBuilder = $urlBuilder;
    }

    /**
     * Data modifier, does nothing in our example.
     *
     * @param array $data
     * @return array
     */
    public function modifyData(array $data)
    {
        return $data;
    }

    /**
     * Meta-data modifier: adds ours fieldset
     *
     * @param array $meta
     * @return array
     */
    public function modifyMeta(array $meta)
    {
        $this->meta = $meta;
        $this->addCustomFieldset();

        return $this->meta;
    }

    /**
     * Merge existing meta-data with our meta-data (do not overwrite it!)
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function addCustomFieldset()
    {
        $this->meta = array_merge_recursive(
            $this->meta,
            [
                static::CUSTOM_FIELDSET_INDEX => $this->getFieldsetConfig(),
            ]
        );
    }

    /**
     * Declare ours fieldset config
     *
     * @return array
     */
    protected function getFieldsetConfig()
    {
        return [
            'arguments' => [
                'data' => [
                    'config' => [
                        'label' => __('DateDelivery Configurations'),
                        'componentType' => Fieldset::NAME,
                        'dataScope' => static::DATA_SCOPE_PRODUCT, // save data in the product data
                        'provider' => static::DATA_SCOPE_PRODUCT . '_data_source',
                        'ns' => static::FORM_NAME,
                        'collapsible' => true,
                        'sortOrder' => 10,
                        'opened' => true,
                    ],
                ],
            ],
            'children' => [
                static::CONTAINER_HEADER_NAME => $this->getHeaderContainerConfig(10),
                static::FIELD_NAME_SELECT => $this->getSelectFieldConfig(30),
            ],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Get config for header container
     *
     * @param int $sortOrder
     * @return array
     */
    protected function getHeaderContainerConfig($sortOrder)
    {
        return [
            'arguments' => [
                'data' => [
                    'config' => [
                        'label' => null,
                        'formElement' => Container::NAME,
                        'componentType' => Container::NAME,
                        'template' => 'ui/form/components/complex',
                        'sortOrder' => $sortOrder,
                        'content' => __('please setup DateDelivery for this product.'),
                    ],
                ],
            ],
            'children' => [],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Example select field config
     *
     * @param $sortOrder
     * @return array
     */
    protected function getSelectFieldConfig($sortOrder)
    {
        return [
            'arguments' => [
                'data' => [
                    'config' => [
                        'label' => __('Day(s) before being ready'),
                        'componentType' => Field::NAME,
                        'formElement' => Select::NAME,
                        'dataScope' => static::FIELD_NAME_SELECT,
                        'dataType' => Text::NAME,
                        'sortOrder' => $sortOrder,
                        'options' => $this->_getOptions(),
                        'visible' => true,
                        'disabled' => false,
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Get days options as an option array:
     *      [
     *          label => string,
     *          value => option_id
     *      ]
     *
     * @return array
     */
    protected function _getOptions()
    {
        $options = [
            0 => [
                'label' => __('0 day'),
                'value' => 1
            ],
            1 => [
                'label' => __('1 day'),
                'value' => 1
            ],
            2 => [
                'label' => __('2 days'),
                'value' => 2
            ],
            3 => [
                'label' => __('3 days'),
                'value' => 3
            ],
            4 => [
                'label' => __('4 days'),
                'value' => 3
            ],
            5 => [
                'label' => __('5 days'),
                'value' => 3
            ],
            6 => [
                'label' => __('6 days'),
                'value' => 3
            ],
            7 => [
                'label' => __('7 days'),
                'value' => 3
            ],
        ];

        return $options;
    }
    }
```

When I try to get the attribut I get 'null' result:

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load(1);
$ntdd_ready_days = $product->getData('ntdd_ready_days');

var_dump($ntdd_ready_days);
```

I can't found where is the problem... Is everything alright ?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access your custom configuration value like this:

```
$product->getData('ntdd_ready_days')
```

This means, `ntdd_ready_days` should be a product attribute. In order to make this work, you need to firstly create a product attribute with code `ntdd_ready_days` and then add a hook to the product save action and collect your select value from the post data, set it your attribute and save it.

But I think you are making thing more complex here. What you need to do here is, just create a select type product attribute via an upgrade script. This will automatically show your product attribute option in the backend and Magento will take care of the saving part.

**[Here is a starter link](https://devdocs.magento.com/videos/fundamentals/add-new-product-attribute/)** for you to get a glimpse on how to achieve the same. Rest, you need to figure it out yourself with the help of Google. :)

Comment: That was the solution! Thank you very much!!! :)